# Diagnostics for the analysis of variance model

Tags: r, anova, lm, diagnostic

I have problem with the diagnostic of the one way analysis of variance model (fitted in R).
I've checked all the assumptions of the analysis of variance

1) "For each level of the within-subjects factor, the dependent variable must have a normal distribution." (shapiro-wilk test) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeated_measures_design#Repeated_measures_ANOVA
Ok, so after there shapiro-wilk failure to reject, I bury my head in the sand and silently assume that this assumption is met.

2) there is homogeneity of the variance of the dependent variable in groups, there are only 2 groups (bartlett test)

3) all observations are independent

Then I fitted model with `aov()` function and after checking whether the p-value is greater or less than 0.05 (doesn't really matter now) I would like to check the **quality of the fit**.

So after I check if residuals have normal distribution and the answer is no, is there any solution? Because that means the quality is weak. For example box-cox transformation for dependent variable?

Should I also check the homogeneity of the variance for residuals ( motivation for this question is that ANOVA is some kind of a linear model )? Can I perform bartlett test again? And what if there is heterogeneity? Should then I use the weighted least squares method **WLSM** (the same as I would be a linear model)?

Are diagnostic plots for `aov()` function, which is similar to `lm()` (as I would perform `plot(lm(  formula ) )` are valid? Or only they are proper for linear model where explanatory variable are continuous?

Thanks for help!

Comment: "*1) dependent variable has normal distribution (shapiro-wilk test)*" ... well, no. Failure to reject doesn't mean it's normal. (similarly for the other two items). Beyond that, I find your question unclear. What do you mean by "quality of the fit" and what does "the answer is no" mean?

Comment: Ok, so after there shapiro-wilk failure to reject, I bury my head in the sand and silently assume that the assumptions are met. What about diagnostics now?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "What about diagnostics now?" One thing I find confusing is that you state the tests you made didn't reject, but then the next thing you seem to be suggesting they did. Can you be more clear what the situation is that you're concerned about?

Comment: 1) I checked whether the assumptions are set. 
2) I assume they are.
3) I fitted model.
4) NOW I want to diagnose whether the quality of fit is good. I want to perform analysis of the residuals - that's what I'm talking about when I say diagnostics.

Comment: I'm confused. How did you check the assumptions in (1) without having residuals? e.g. how do you test normality of residuals if you don't have them yet? What happened in (1)?

Comment: The assumption of ANOVA is that dependent variable has normal distribution? I checked that?

Comment: Check here assumptions for the Repeated measures design ANOVA.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeated_measures_design

Comment: It doesn't say "the dependent variable has a normal distribution" there. (Also you really should have made clear you were dealing with repeated measures. You said "one way anova" in your question, which is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_analysis_of_variance))

Comment: "For each level of the within-subjects factor, the dependent variable must have a normal distribution."

OK I'll edit my post. But that's not the heart of the matter.

Comment: It kind of is. You seem to be checking the same assumptions twice ... but by doing it before you have residuals, your ability to assess it sensibly is limited.

Comment: So what does it mean when: For each level of the within-subjects factor, the dependent variable have a normal distribution BUT residuals have not got normal distribution?

Comment: It almost certainly means that your power when you're checking within levels is low, due to low sample sizes. Generally, you don't assess your assumptions until you have residuals, since they're generally best performed on residuals (and even then I wouldn't formally test them).

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I didn't think about low power. And your are right that the sample may be small (41 observations in each of the 2 groups). Can I ask one more question? What do you mean by writing 'until you have residuals' - I though there are *always* residuals?

Comment: I usually only have residuals after I fit models. Before then I just have the observations.

Comment: There are some other possibilities, though, that could have normality within each thing (sorry, each level of the within-subjects factor), but non-normality when you collect all the residuals --  such as you're checking normality when you have strong heteroskedasticity. You should check the regression and anova assumptions in the right order (assumptions about means before variances before shapes - if any don't hold, the later ones can't be properly assessed)

Comment: Can I do anything, after assumptions holds but residuals are not normally distributed? Box-cox transformation on dependent variable? Weighted least squares method?

Comment: Depends on how non-normal and how big the sample size is. In mild cases or large sample sizes I'd likely ignore it. Otherwise, I'd probably look at some kind of resampling (bootstrapping or permutation say) approach, though it depends on the exact model. I might use rank based approaches in ordinary ANOVA, though a permutation test is about as easy to do - it depends on the audience as well. Or I might use a GLM, especially if there's also mean-related heteroskedasticity. Other assumptions than normality (such as independence and constant variance) matter more.